# sqlite3: Table schema not copying from main database to second database

Tags: c++, sql, database, sqlite

I am attempting to copy the same table schema and a select number of entries from my main database to a new secondary database. I am able to create the second database `START.sql` and inside it, a table called `copied`, however the schema between that and the main  `masterDatabaseTest` differ and as a result I receive the error:

```
table START.copied has 1 columns but 5 values were supplied
```

**The code:**

```c++
void newLog(std::string tableName, std::string timeStart, std::string timeEnd)
{
    char *err_msg = NULL;
    int rc= -1;

    std::string dbLogName       = timeStart;
    std::string dbLogName2      = dbLogName + ".sql";

    std::string attachQuery     = "ATTACH DATABASE 'START.sql' AS 'START';";
    std::string copyTable       = "CREATE TABLE START.copied AS SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' and name='masterDatabaseTest';";
    std::string insertCopied    = "INSERT INTO START.copied SELECT * from sqlite_master where type='table' and name='masterDatabaseTest';";
    std::string detach          = "DETACH DATABASE START;";

    std::cout   << dbLogName << "\n" 
                << attachQuery << "\n"
                << copyTable   << "\n" 
                << insertCopied << "\n" 
                << detach << std::endl;

    sqlite3_exec(db, "BEGIN TRANSACTION;", NULL, NULL, 0);
    rc = sqlite3_open(databaseName.c_str(), &db); // CREATES DATABASE
    std::cout << "OPEN: " << rc << std::endl;

    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, attachQuery.c_str(), NULL, 0, &err_msg);
    std::cout << "ATTACH: " << rc << std::endl;
    if(rc != 0){
        std::cout << err_msg << std::endl;
    }

    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, copyTable.c_str(), NULL, 0, &err_msg);
    std::cout << "copyTable: " << rc <<  std::endl;
    if(rc != 0){
        std::cout << err_msg << std::endl;
    }

    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, insertCopied.c_str(), NULL, 0, &err_msg);
    std::cout << "insertCopied: " << rc << std::endl;
    if(rc != 0){
        std::cout << err_msg << std::endl;
    }

    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, detach.c_str(), NULL, 0, &err_msg);
    std::cout << "detach: " << rc << std::endl;
    if(rc != 0){
        std::cout << err_msg << std::endl;
    }

    sqlite3_exec(db, "END TRANSACTION;", NULL, NULL, 0);
}
```

**inside commandline sqlite3 database.sql:**

```
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE masterDatabaseTest (ID INTEGER,RECORDTIME BIGINT,TYPE INTEGER,TIMESTAMP BIGINT,ENCODER1 INTEGER,ENCODER2 INTEGER,ENCODER3 INTEGER,ENCODER4 INTEGER,ENCODER5 INTEGER);
```

**inside commandline sqlite3 START.sql**

```
sqlite> .schema                                                                
CREATE TABLE copied(sql TEXT);
```

Comment: Right. The `CREATE` query creates a table with 1 column; this `SELECT * from sqlite_master` selects 5 columns, and 5 into 1 won't go. It is unclear, at least to me, what result you are looking for.

Comment: @DinoCoderSaurus that is my problem... i want an exact copy of the schema of masterDatabaseTest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out my problem :)

the `db` instance was not pointing to the correct database, so although I was able to execute it correctly in commandline, the actual program has no initialised the database connection so the `sqlite3_exec` command was pointing to nothing.

Fixing that I was able to execute the commands with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want "*an exact copy of the schema of masterDatabaseTest*", you do not need to use `sqlite_master`. The DDL query

```
CREATE TABLE START.copied AS SELECT * from masterDatabaseTest
```

will accomplish that. If you want a select number of entries, add a `WHERE` clause. If you do not want any rows from the source table, add a `WHERE 0`; it will create the schema and will not select any rows.

Comment: Tried that. It tells me "no such database as masterDatabaseTest" and yes it exists

Comment: I don't know why it would give a "no such database" error since `masterDatabaseTest` is a table (based on the SELECT query and the `.schema` result).